# mongoose schema to hold site statistics

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Say I want my front page to show statistics like "total number of comments in whole site". Would it be better to do a query on all documents in the Comments collection and get the length, or would it be easier to have a single collection for statistics?

My initial instinct is to just query the Comments collection and grab length, but as comments grow, the query will become expensive. Using a collection for a few documents seem to not be efficient, and would require more logic to update it as comments are made.

Which way is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Correct" is subjective, but effectively your second strategy is just caching the `count()` in another collection. It would be more typical to use an in-memory cache (eg `memcached`) for live stats since the counts are transient and you probably don't need the I/O overhead of persisting them (unless you are also plotting some sort of history?).  You can prime the cache with the current counts when your application starts.

It's worth noting that your cached counter doesn't have to be an *exact* match for the `count()` returned by a database query.  Once you have a starting count, you probably know the only way for this to change is by adding or deleting a comment.  Using an approach like [mongoose-lifecyle](https://github.com/fzaninotto/mongoose-lifecycle) you could adjust the cached count based on events in your Comment model, i.e.: `afterInsert` (+1) and possibly `afterRemove` (-1).  Most sites only like to advertise statistics that are increasing, so the interpretation of "total comments" is typically "total comments (ever)" rather than "total comments currently published".